# Concatenate two AND queries in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my current MySQL Table:

```
Crop             ID  Price  DateUpdated             Area       Region
Onion            4   50     2014-02-05 21:42:26     Bulua      X
Onion            5   20     2014-02-05 21:42:26     Lapasan    X
Onion            14  34.4   2014-02-05 23:12:21     Cogon      X
Onion            15  54     2014-02-07 02:40:13     Cogon      X
Onion            15  84     2014-02-07 02:40:13     DMarket    XI
```

I want to output all `'Crops'` with their latest `'Price'` with their corresponding `'Region'`.
So entries that contains the specific `Product` AND `Region` with their latest price is what I needed.

Assuming that:

```
$product = 'Onion';
$region = 'X';
```

And the query as:

```
$crop_multi = $db->query("SELECT Crop, Price, Area, Region  
                FROM crops cr WHERE TRIM(Crop) = '{$product}' 
                AND DateUpdated = (SELECT MAX(DateUpdated) FROM crops WHERE Crop = cr.Crop AND TRIM(Crop) = '{$product}' AND TRIM(Region) = '{$region}')");
$message = "Price of {$product} in markets of Region {$region}:<br>";

            foreach ($crop_multi->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $row) {
            $add = "P{$row->Price}/kilo in {$row->Area}<br>";
            $message .= $add;
                }
            echo $message;
```

The desired output would be:

```
Price of Onion in markets of Region X:
P50/kilo in Bulua
P20/kilo in Lapasan
P54/kilo in Cogon
```

- However, my code above only outputs a single line (crop with the
  'latest' price) when used in `phpmyadmin query function` even if other entries meet the criteria of the query.
- The foreach
  loop works fine with another syntax on my problem so I don't think
  that's the problem.
- I have tried changing the $product into $region but it instead outputs multiple entries, so yes its a failed attempt.

EDIT: Just a clarification, the code above is an excerpt.
I'm having problems on the Query on `$crop_multi`

Comment: I can see syntax error in your code. What is `else` part doing without `if`. Can you post your complete working code ?

Comment: @Rikesh: its an excerpt sorry, just the Mysql fix would be fine :)

Comment: We require what comes after `$crop_multi = $db->query(..) to be able to help you. Your code may only show 1 result.

Comment: @davidstrachan: I have reverted it back to the original version, I edited it last time so that it won't be mistaken as a PHP problem but a Mysql query one. Sorry about that.

Comment: How about a GROUP BY on Crop and Region and then ORDER BY DateUpdated and a LIMIT of 1

Comment: It is best not to assume what is causing the problem. With the whole code we can see that if `$crop_multi` has a result the output would show. Without seeing the `foreach (` loop it is harder tell whither it is the query that is at fault or otherwise. Remember SO Questions and Answers are for more  than the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try  this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Crop, Price, Area, Region FROM crops  tb1
WHERE DateUpdated = (SELECT MAX(DateUpdated) FROM crops tb2 WHERE tb1.Crop = tb2.Crop AND tb1.Area = tb2.Area AND tb1.Region = tb2.Region)
AND TRIM(Crop) = '{$product}' AND TRIM(Region) = '{$region}';
```

Comment: The code worked sir. If you have time, can you please explain the subqueries that you used? I have yet to fully understand this type of syntaxes, to avoid future mishaps and also for people who have the same problem. :)

Comment: Sure! My subquery Finds the last date `MAX(DateUpdated)` maching the columns of two the tables (alias tb1 and tb2), in this case same tables: `tb1.Crop = tb2.Crop AND tb1.Area = tb2.Area AND tb1.Region = tb2.Region`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
    "SELECT Crop, Price, Area, Region  
    FROM crops cr WHERE TRIM(Crop) = ".$product." 
    AND DateUpdated = (SELECT MAX(DateUpdated) FROM crops WHERE Crop = cr.Crop AND TRIM(Crop) = ".$product." AND TRIM(Region) = ".$region."')"
```

Comment: Yes the, however the code that you sent me is similar to what I have in my question :(

Comment: please clarify what the query is returning, and what you expect it to return

Comment: I need the Product AND Region with their latest prices. The query above when used in phpmyadmin only outputs a single line even if there are other entries that fit the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT Crop, Price, Area, Region
FROM crops cr WHERE TRIM(Crop) = '{$product}'
AND TRIM(Region) = '{$region}'
AND DateUpdated IN(SELECT MAX(DateUpdated) FROM crops WHERE Crop = cr.Crop AND TRIM(Crop) = '{$product}' GROUP BY Crop, Area)
```

Cheers

Comment: It gave an error on my fetchAll sir. I put it after the WHERE clause and changed '{$product}' and '{$region}' but still gave the same error.